# Trying to figure where a certain transfer function starts in the magnitude plot

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I've been trying to draw, with asymptotic approximation, the Bode diagram of the following transfer function

$$G(s) = \frac{\frac{1}{80} - s}{s^2 (s + 4) (s + 5)}$$

The thing is, I don't why the amplitude plot start a little before $100$ *dB*.. I have two poles in the origin, therefore the  line should start at $120$ dB (correct me if I'm wrong) with a pendency of *$-40$ dB/decade*. I calculated the *Bode gain*, which is equals to 1/1600; by converting the amount in dB, it returns *$-64.08$ dB*, so the amplitude plot should be vertically translated of *-$64.08$ dB*, thus the amplitude diagram should start at $120$ - $64.04$ = $55.96$ dB, but the result doesn't match with the several diagrams I draw in Maple and Matlab.

[Maple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dU5Aj.png) ,
[Matlab graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gmYz.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the plot MAPLE or MATLAB give correctly? The $G(s)$ you give does not have a finite DC gain, i.e. the limit as $\omega\to 0$ of $\left\|G(j\omega)\right\|$ is unbounded. So the mag plot of $G(s)$ doesn't "start" at any particular value: it will entirely depend on what your choice of lowest frequency $\omega$ is on the plot.

Comment: But if that's the case, then why both graphs start at (more or less) the same point? See the screenshots

Comment: When you also have to state where they start. Without stating this the only natural assumption for the starting point is $0$ rad/s. However, both plots start at $10^{-4}$ rad/s.

Comment: In conclusion, why  both diagrams start at a little less before 100 dB?

Comment: Both plots start evaluating the frequency response at $\omega=10^{-4}~\frac{\mathrm{rad}}{s}$ and you can verify that $\left\|G(10^{-4} j)\right\| \approx 96~\mathrm{dB}.$

Comment: Understood, thank you !